# firefox IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have outputted all my variables to the console to try to debug this.

My destination canvas size is 473 x 473.

```
canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 335, 419, 23, 23, 335, 419);
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I have sketched it out. Start clipping source image at (0,0), go through its full with and height (335 x 419) and on the destination start copying at (23,23) and then to the image width and height (335  x 419). I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: What exactly is `image` and is its `width` really greater than or equal to `335` and its `height` greater than or equal to `419`?

Comment: The image not being large enough is the only cause of the problem that I can think of… as a workaround you could use the arguments `image.width>335?335:image.width, image.height>419?419:image.height` instead of `335, 419`.

Comment: Image is 335 pixels wide and 419 pixels high

Comment: Is the image loaded before it’s being drawn on the canvas? And again: what exactly is `image`? An `HTMLImageElement`? An `ImageData` object?

Comment: image is an HTMLImageElement created as so: var image = new Image();

Comment: Ok, could you maybe show the full code of creating the image, setting the image source, waiting for the image to load and then drawing it and anything else that might be relevant to the image?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No. Sorry nothing I tried worked.  I invested about 6 hours to try different things and nothing worked. I ended having to cut my loses and turn off this feature for Firefox users. At least its a minor feature

Comment: Maybe a JSFiddle would be helpful.